# Error while testing my async function using XUNIT in c# .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, fakeiteasy

I have convereted my IEnumerable function into a (public async Task<List>) however im having issues fixing my unit test for that specific part. Im using fakeiteasy to mock my data, and assert that my result.count == 1 after fetching my data.

However i get this specific error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebAPI__CodeFirst.Classes.Customer]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebAPI__CodeFirst.Classes.Customer]'.

This is my ICustomerRepository

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Task<List<Customer>> GetAllCustomers();
}
```

This is my Test for my getAll

```
private readonly ICustomerRepository _repo;
private readonly CustomersController _controller;

public CustomerControllerTests()
{
    _repo = A.Fake<ICustomerRepository>();
    _controller = new CustomersController(_repo);
}


[Fact]
public void GetAll_Returns_All_Customers()
{
    // Arrange
    var customers = new List<Customer>() { new Customer { customer_ID = 1 } };
    A.CallTo(() => _repo.GetAllCustomers()).Returns(customers);

    // Act
    var result = _controller.GetAll();

    // Assert
    Assert.Single(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous, and your test is for code that executes synchronously. Make your unit test asynchronous as well. Also, your method signature returns a Task wrapped result, not just the result.

As a side note it is considered best practice to add the word `Async` to your method name as a suffix if it returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`. It becomes apparent to the caller that this is an asynchronous call without having to check the return type. So `GetAllCustomersAsync` instead of `GetAllCustomers`.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAll_Returns_All_Customers()
{
    // Arrange
    var customers = new List<Customer>() { new Customer { customer_ID = 1 } };
    A.CallTo(() => _repo.GetAllCustomers()).Returns(Task.FromResult(customers));

    // Act
    var result = await _controller.GetAll();

    // Assert
    Assert.Single(result);
}
```